# GWT права пользователей

Tags: java, java-ee, архитектура, gwt

Добрый день. Следующая проблема. Есть проект на GWT. Заказчик хочет, чтобы для конкретной роли пользователя можно было включать/выключать определенные виджеты или определенные поля в виджетах. Раньше мы хардкодили права на клиенте и на сервере. Примерно так:

```
    // Клиент. Заполняем виджет информации о сотруднике
    if (isAccess(getCurrentPost(), ADMIN, TESTER)) {
       textBoxName.setText(staff.getName());
    }

    // Сервер. Асинхронный метод, получающий данные для виджета с информацией о сотруднике.
    if (isAccess(getCurrentPost(), ADMIN, TESTER)) {
       staff.setName(name);
    }
    return staff;
```

Это было ужасно неудобно, права на клиенте и сервере постоянно не совпадали. Например: пользователь видит пустое поле ввода, и думает информация отсутствует, а на деле - на сервере забыли добавить ему права. Обратная ситуация связана с безопасностью данных. Теперь всё стало еще сложнее: разрешенные должности `ADMIN, TESTER` будут храниться в базе данных. Часть этих прав будет загружаться при авторизации пользователя, часть прав (зависящих от пришедших данных) будет загружаться по мере необходимости. Концепция очень неудобная... Хотелось бы, что-то похожее на   JSF, чтобы код клиентского виджета генерировался на сервере. Но JSF нам не подходит, потому что у нас огромное количество клиентской логики, да и проект довольно большой. Если есть какие-то предложения как это реализовать 'меньшей кровью', был бы очень благодарен